# Vue dynamic emits

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

How do you emit any string run time? I have the following code:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
interface Action {
  icon: string;
  emit: string;
}

const props = defineProps<{
  modelValue: Action[];
}>();

const emit = defineEmits<{
  (event: string, value: boolean): void;
}>();

const actionClicked = (action: Action) => {
  emit(action.emit, true);
};
</script>
```

but I get

> Component emitted event "MYACTION" but its neither declared in the emits options or as an "onMYACTION" prop.

I could do:

```
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (event: "MYACTION", value: boolean): void;
}>();
```

But "MYACTION" is just an example the event name needs to be dynamic.

Comment: The error message makes an observation, and then states two possible conditions that you are not fulfilling relative to that observation.

Comment: But I can't do either of those things because the even name name needs to be dynamic

Comment: Add that clarification to your question.  It would also be helpful if we knew why you need it to be completely dynamic.

Comment: There's no way to do that dynamically, the emitted events should be explicitly defined as we do with prop

Comment: Is this a regression from vue 2 to vue 3, I'm trying to rewrite a component but keep its API

Comment: The dynamic event name is likely constrained to a specific subset of strings. You could create a type that contains just those strings, and annotate the event argument and `Action#emit` with that type.

Comment: @tony19 no because of separation of concerns this component has no knowledge of what Action(s) the parent will use.